# swap working for `swapExactETHForTokens` but `swapExactTokensForTokens` resulting in an error

Tags: web3.py, uniswap, hardhat, swaps, fantom

I have been trying to write token swap scripts for Spookyswap on Fantom (so the transaction formatting should be pre EIP-1559) in python using web3.py.

I have forked Fantom via Hardhat for testing purposes.

The script below, using `swapExactETHForTokens`, works and results in swapping 30 FTM for MIM.

```
path = [wFTM, MIM]
contract_txn = contract_SPOOKY_ROUTER.functions.swapExactETHForTokens( 0, path , address_wallet, block['timestamp']+30 ).buildTransaction({
                            # 'type': '0x2',
                            'from': address_wallet,
                            'chainId':  31337,    # FTM 
                            'value' : Web3.toWei(30, 'ether'),
                            'gas': 250000,
                            'gasPrice': w3.eth.gas_price, #Web3.toWei('300', 'gwei'),
                            'nonce': nonce,
})

signed = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(contract_txn, privatekey)
w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed.rawTransaction)
nonce += 1
```

However, I have not been able to get `swapExactTokensForTokens` to work despite the two functions [supposedly having the same input arguments](https://ftmscan.com/address/0xf491e7b69e4244ad4002bc14e878a34207e38c29#writeContract).

Below is my attempt to get `swapExactTokensForTokens` to work. (I have tinkered with the parameters and tried moving them around as well.)

Any help would be appreciated.

```
path = [MIM, fohm]
contract_txn = contract_SPOOKY_ROUTER.functions.swapExactTokensForTokens(num, 0,  path , address_wallet, block['timestamp']+30 ).buildTransaction({
                            # 'type': '0x2',
                            #'from': address_wallet,
                            'chainId':  31337,    # FTM 
                            'value' : Web3.toWei(30, 'ether'),
                            'gas': 250000,
                            'gasPrice': w3.eth.gas_price, #Web3.toWei('300', 'gwei'),
                            'nonce': nonce,
})

signed = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(contract_txn, privatekey)
w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed.rawTransaction)
nonce += 1
```

The error message is usually the following:

```
raise ValueError(response["error"])
ValueError: {'code': -32603, 'message': 'Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string', 'data': {'txHash': '0xa32dfefb03e27bb82490e5b8a05957ab87e0097a0b7da997010c239a8a35a294'}}
```

or

```
ValueError: {'code': -32603, 'message': "Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'UniswapV2Router: EXPIRED'", 'data': {'txHash': '0x1871c1afb2967895aad61440ec22d64400a1874582f9b45651a1067ac3ca7891'}}
```

I did approve all relevant contracts before running the blocks of code above

```
approval_wFTM = contract_wFTM.functions.approve(address_wallet, 2**256-1)
approval_fohm = contract_fohm.functions.approve(address_wallet, 2**256-1)
approval_MIM = contract_MIM.functions.approve(address_wallet, 2**256-1)
```

Comment: It seems that you're a sending value of `30 ether` to `swapExactTokensForTokens` which is not a payable function

Answer (score -1):

I am just as stuck as you are, but i believe it's due to the stable: bool param that needs to be true whenever there is stable in the route, or false when not. I will look at this tomorrow

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/69822)